# iOS How to make facebook or tumblr dynamic tableview cell height for url image

Tags: ios, uitableview

i'm junior iOS programmer my question is how to make facebook or tumblr dynamic tableview cell height for url image 
My server give url string for image and my app get json string and display images from `UITableView`. However my app handle `UIImage` by `SDWebImage` and problem is `uitableview` cell height  have didn't change. my code `heightForRowAtindex` delegate method is

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        return 112.0f;

    } else {

        NSMutableDictionary *userPostDataDic = [userPostContentData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

        JALabel *userPostContentLabel = [[JALabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 34, 220, 60)];
        userPostContentLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
        userPostContentLabel.text = [userPostDataDic valueForKey:@"home_board_text"];
        [userPostContentLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular" size:13.0f]];
        userPostContentLabel.textColor = [CommonViewController colorWithHexString:@"00A6F8"];

        [userPostContentLabel setFrame:[CommonViewController getDynamicUILabelHeightWithLabel:userPostContentLabel contentString:[userPostDataDic valueForKey:@"home_board_text"]]];


        if ([[userPostDataDic valueForKey:@"home_board_image"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            return [CommonViewController getDynamicUILabelHeightWithLabel:userPostContentLabel contentString:[userPostDataDic valueForKey:@"home_board_text"]].size.height + 34 + 50;

        } else {

            NSString *homeCellIdentifier = @"magazineTableViewCell";

            HomeTableViewCell *homeTableCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:homeCellIdentifier];

            if (homeTableCell == nil) {

                homeTableCell = [Face3Utils getViewFromNib:@"HomeTableViewXib" class:[HomeTableViewCell class]];

            }

            //UIImageView *forImageHeightImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 34, 220, 100)];

            [homeTableCell.userPostContentImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userPostDataDic valueForKey:@"home_board_image"]]
                                        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iu1.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

                                        }];

            homeTableCell.userPostContentImageView.image = [CommonViewController imageWithImage:homeTableCell.userPostContentImageView.image scaledToWidth:220.0f];

            return [CommonViewController getDynamicUILabelHeightWithLabel:userPostContentLabel contentString:[userPostDataDic valueForKey:@"home_board_text"]].size.height + 34 + [homeTableCell.userPostContentImageView.image size].height + 50;
        }
    }
}
```

Almost stackoverflow question is how to make dynamic tableview cell height for `UILabel`
but to use url image dynamic `UITableView` cell height is not exist Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to really re-word your question as it doesnt make sense.
A few problems you have i can see, is that you are downloading an image in the height for row, you should not do this.
The process should be something like this:

- Get json from your server about data/user/whatever
- Download the images
- Refresh your tableview, after gettng the images, if you wish to dynamically set the hight for each image.

The other option is to have a set width and height, then just aspect fit those images.